Change element within selected List View
How when reacting to a selected item in collection view:
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <HorizontalStackLayout x:Name="horizontalStackLayout ">
            <Label
                Text="{Binding title}" />
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>

and the code-behind:
    private async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         // ???
         // this returns null:
         // HorizontalStackLayout selectedView = (HorizontalStackLayout) ((CollectionView) sender).FindByName("horizontalStackLayout");
    }

to find the HorizontalStackLayout and change its attribute?

Do not try to manipulate the visual tree of a templated control.  You should use data binding to accomplish this

x:Name attribute inside a DataTemplate does not directly associate the named element with the CollectionView's FindByName method. Each item in the CollectionView has its own DataTemplate. So your approach won't work.
If Manipulating properties of HorizontalStackLayout is you goal, Then you need to find another way.
One Way is to create new properties in you model class and bind them to the property you want to manipulate when selection changed.
public class Item
{
   public string title;
   public Color ItemBackgroundColor = Colors.Red; // new property in model class
}

in xaml bind it
 <DataTemplate>
     <HorizontalStackLayout BackgroundColor={Binding ItemBackgroundColor} x:Name="horizontalStackLayout ">
        <Label
            Text="{Binding title}" />
     </HorizontalStackLayout>
</DataTemplate>

Now you can set the property in SelectionChanged event
private async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var selectedItem in e.CurrentSelection)
    {
        if(selectedItem is Item _item)
        {
           _item.ItemBackgroundColor = Colors.Green;
        }
     }
}

Note: Make sure changes in model properties are notified to view.

One of the easier ways "when reacting to a selected item in a collection view" is to bind the SelectedItem property. You mention changing an attribute of HorizontalStackLayout so let's say for example that you want its background color to turn blue when selected.  I kludged a CollectionView onto the MAUI default as a minimal example of doing this.


<CollectionView 
    MinimumHeightRequest="400"
    BackgroundColor="Azure"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    ItemsSource="{Binding items}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="1" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentView>
                <Frame 
                    Margin="2"
                    Padding="10"
                    BackgroundColor="White"
                    CornerRadius="10"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    InputTransparent="true">
                    <HorizontalStackLayout
                        BackgroundColor="{Binding HorizontalStackLayoutColor}">
                        <Label 
                            Text="{Binding title}" 
                            TextColor="{Binding LabelTextColor}"
                            FontSize="16"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            Padding="5"/>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </Frame>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightBlue" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </ContentView>
        </DataTemplate>                   
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>


Binding context for MainPage
class MainPageBindingContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>
    {
        new Item{title = "Item A"},
        new Item{title = "Item B"},
    };

    // Because we're in "single" mode, we bind SelectedItem, not SelectedItems
    public Item? SelectedItem
    {
        get => _selectedItem;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_selectedItem, value))
            {
                _selectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                // Quick and dirty. You will want to improve on this.
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    item.IsSelected = ReferenceEquals(_selectedItem, item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Item? _selectedItem = default;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null) => 
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}


Binding context for Item
class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string title
    {
        get => IsSelected ? $"{_title} SELECTED"  : _title;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_title, value))
            {
                _title = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    string _title = "{New Item}";

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get => _isSelected;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_isSelected, value))
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HorizontalStackLayoutColor));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LabelTextColor));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(title));
            }
        }
    }
    bool _isSelected = default;

    public Color HorizontalStackLayoutColor => IsSelected ? Colors.CornflowerBlue : Colors.White;
    public Color LabelTextColor => IsSelected ? Colors.White : Colors.Black;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}


clone
